# Explicit deletion of copy constructor and assignment in Pybind11

Tags: copy, copy-constructor, delete-operator, pybind11, pybinding

If you have a class with explicit deletion of the copy constructor and assignment operation as in the following example

```
        Foo(const Foo& other) = delete;
        Foo& operator=(const Foo& other) = delete;
```

how can you specify it in the Pybind11 wrapper for the class? Ultimately the purpose is to follow the intended use for the C++ class which enforces moving and forbids copying

```
        Foo(const Foo& other) = delete;
        Foo& operator=(const Foo& other) = delete;
        Foo(Foo&& other) = default;
        Foo& operator=(Foo&& other) = default;
```

Comment: Copying on the python side is by reference anyway, so I don't think you have to do anything.